Apollo Kotlin 4 - Receiving 403 Error Instead of GraphQL Error Response on Incorrect Login
I'm working on a Compose Multiplatform project using Apollo Kotlin 4 for GraphQL communication. When I attempt to log in with incorrect credentials, the server sends a JSON response containing a GraphQL error:
    {
       "errors": [
        {
            "extensions": {
                "reason": "Incorrect username or password.",
                "show_resend": false
            }
        }
    ]
}

However, my Apollo client is throwing an ApolloNetworkException with the message "Http request failed with status code 403" and doesn't provide access to the actual GraphQL error details.
Interestingly, when I test the same mutation in Postman, it correctly displays the GraphQL error response.
My question is:
What could be causing this discrepancy between the Apollo client and Postman? Is there a configuration issue on the client or server side?
How can I properly catch and handle this GraphQL error response in my Apollo Kotlin code so I can display the "Incorrect username or password" message to the user?
